# Create external HIVE table from files with different record formats for a csv file

Tags: hive, hdfs

I have a CSV file with different record formats that is defined by the first column value:
Sample Data:

```
"EL","XXXXXXX", 2017-07-17
"EH","XXXXXXX",1,2017-07-17,"AAA"
"BI","XXXXXXX","AAA","BBBB"
```

In this case, I am getting the file with 3 defined record types. 
Is there a way to load this to different hive tables ?

Comment: You could define a generic table, with 5 generic String columns, then define 3 views tapping that table with the appropriate WHERE filtering, and the appropriate column selection/conversion/renaming.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter do we need to define the longest number of string columns for the table..since in my case, the number of columns in each record type is variable?

Comment: If this is one time creation of external table, write a shell script to move the records into three different files based on first column value and then create external tables on top of each file. You can do this with writing a pig script too

Comment: @hadooper, i had that as an alternative approach so far..i was looking if there are alternatives on not splitting the file and still able to create the necessary external tables

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**

```
create table el (s1 string,d1 date);
create table eh (s1 string,i1 int,dt1 date,s2 string);
create table bi (s1 string,s2 string,s3 string);
```

---

```
create external table myfile 
(
    c1  string
   ,c2  string
   ,c3  string
   ,c4  string
   ,c5  string
)

row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties 
(
    'separatorChar' = ','
   ,'quoteChar'     = '"'
   ,'escapeChar'    = '\\'
)  
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from myfile;

+-----+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
| c1  |    c2    |      c3      |     c4      |  c5   |
+-----+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
| EL  | XXXXXXX  |  2017-07-17  | NULL        | NULL  |
| EH  | XXXXXXX  | 1            | 2017-07-17  | AAA   |
| BI  | XXXXXXX  | AAA          | BBBB        | NULL  |
+-----+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

---

```
from myfile
insert into el select c2,c3       where c1='EL'
insert into eh select c2,c3,c4,c5 where c1='EH'
insert into bi select c2,c3,c4    where c1='BI'
;
```

---

```
select * from el;

+----------+-------------+
|    s1    |     d1      |
+----------+-------------+
| XXXXXXX  | 2017-07-17  |
+----------+-------------+
```

---

```
select * from eh;

+----------+-----+-------------+------+
|    s1    | i1  |     dt1     |  s2  |
+----------+-----+-------------+------+
| XXXXXXX  | 1   | 2017-07-17  | AAA  |
+----------+-----+-------------+------+
```

---

```
select * from bi;

+----------+------+-------+
|    s1    |  s2  |  s3   |
+----------+------+-------+
| XXXXXXX  | AAA  | BBBB  |
+----------+------+-------+
```

Comment: just to re-asked my assumption with this approach.. I need to define the external table using the len(columns) for the largest record.. ?

Comment: Yes (The record with the maximum number of fields)